# Maatwebsite import doesnt work in ubunutu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, import, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel

When I try to import an excel sheet using Maatwebsite 3.1 version on server which is in Ubuntu, I am getting such type of error.

> Error:
>
> Maatwebsite \ Excel \ Exceptions \ NoTypeDetectedException
>
> No ReaderType or WriterType could be detected. Make sure you either
>   pass a valid extension to the filename or pass an explicit type.

Controller

```
$path = $request->file('mcafile')->getRealPath();
$data = \Excel::import(new UsersImport,$path);
```

But the same import excel code works fine in my local windows machine.
Every code and file that I upload are same. But works different in local and in server. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So the issue was with the getRealPath(). 
Initially I was trying to get the path by,

```
$path = $request->file('mcafile')->getRealPath();
```

But now I changed it by storing it to a temp and retrieve the path from there, and send it to the function.
Like this,

```
$path1 = $request->file('mcafile')->store('temp'); 
$path=storage_path('app').'/'.$path1;  
$data = \Excel::import(new UsersImport,$path);
```

Comment: This was very helpful, in addition, don't forget to `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  //$path = $request->file('mcafile')->getRealPath();
    $data = \Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->file);
```

Answer (score 0):

add  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form