# No ReaderType or WriterType could be detected. Make sure you either pass a valid extension to the filename or pass an explicit type

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

While trying to export a excel I get this error , I am  using Laravel 9 and maatwebsite 3.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this issue. It happened to me also in Laravel 9 when I tried to import an Excel using [this package](https://laravel-excel.com/). In localhost (Windows 10) worked fine, but when deploying it, I got the error.

The problem was that I was trying to pass in the temporal file path:

```php
$items = (new ItemsImport)->toCollection($request->file('file')->getPathName())[0];
```

Now, I pass directly the file. I don't get that error anymore. It works fine:

```php
$items = (new ItemsImport)->toCollection($request->file('file'))[0];
```

I am deploying in a Linux Machine. Seems Linux and Windows treat differently the temporal Laravel files. To test it out, I did:

```php
dd($request->file('file')->getPathName());
```

And in both OSs and I got different results. In Windows:

```php
"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\php5DF9.tmp"
```

In Linux:

```php
"myRoute/tmp/phps27wPC"
```

So as said, seems they treat the paths differently. In Linux, the path doesn't have an extension, so the program can't guess the reader type.

More info [here](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/2201).

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to include **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in the form line because inputting files requires that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store the file in `temp` then retrieve it and send it to the function. Following this link is the solution [click here for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105889/maatwebsite-import-doesnt-work-in-ubunutu/57106453#57106453)